# uploading a cronjob

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to use a cronjob to execute a php file on a unix webserver (I use godaddy for hosting). But I am generally new to web dev., so I am unsure how to actually make sure the file is executing. The job just needs to run a php script everyday at 2:15 AM. this is what I have:

```
MAILTO=cron@email.domain.com
15 2 * * * http://mydomainname.com/refresh.php
```

How do I specify the file name to run, doesn't seem like I should give it a URL? Not sure where to find the file path on godaddy... Do I just load this as a .txt file?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I specify the file name to run

You type it where you currently have a URI.

> doesn't seem like I should give it a URL?

Correct. You need a shell command.

> Not sure where to find the file path on godaddy...

We don't know where you keep your files on your server. I suggest SSHing in and looking around.

> Do I just load this as a .txt file?

Generally you would run `crontab -e` and then use the presented editor to enter it.

Comment: I do. I was thinking that but my fingers just didn't agree with my brain. They need to learn who is in charge around here.

Answer (score 1):

You can give path to file and run it using PHP command-line.

`15 2 * * * home/path/to/command/your_php_script.php`

`15 2 * * * home/path/to/command/the_command.sh`

Godaddy path is displayed Under Web hosting in the Server section, your hosting account's Absolute Hosting Path displays.

Tip: You can create a php file with `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` then visit that page from browser this should give absolute hosting path to you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an URL in cron. It is unaware of URLs. instead create a script to run PHP with the appropriate file. You need to then supply the correct path to that script.

A useful trick to test it is to use `at` first - you can then ensure that the thing will work with `cron`.